# What do you call a function differentiated with respect to all of its arguments?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, terminology

Just a simple question.

Let $f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$ be a smooth function. Is there a particular name for the function

$$\frac{\partial^n f}{\partial x_1 \, \partial x_2 \cdots \partial x_n}$$

Comment: I don't know any particular name for this.  But if you want to think about $n$th derivatives of products/compositions/quotients/whatever, then _first_ think about the problem with _this_ kind of $n$th derivative, and afterwards with $\partial^n f/\partial x^n$, etc.

Comment: It doesn't usually have a name.  Since it's not coordinate-change invariant (see the chain rule), it's not a geometrically-interesting concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does not have a name. We call it the $n$-th partial difference of $f$ w.r.t. the vector $x$ or variables $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x_n$.